# Automatically open a PowerShell session on Hyper-V Server 2008 R2 or Windows Server 2008 R2 Core?

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2008-r2, hyper-v

I have a virtual server running with Hyper-v r2 sp1 (standalone product). I imagine it applies also to W2K8 Core install.

When I connect to the remote desktop, both `sconfig.cmd` and `cmd.exe` are launched for the admin shell.

I'd like to launch (beside or in replacment of cmd.exe) a powershell session whenever a user log on to the server.

How can I do that ?

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the command prompt, run `regedit`. Browse to `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`. Add a new string value with name `PowerShell` and value `cmd.exe /k C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe`.

The original command prompt is launched from `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\Shell`. You can change that value if you want, too.

Comment: simply and working. Thanks. Do you know if it's possible to replace the `cmd.exe` (as it's not ran from the `Run` key). I vaguely remember there is Shell value somewhere in the registry, but didn't remember which one

Comment: For diagnosing all auto run issues I highly recommend Autoruns from formerly sysinternals now from MS: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902

Comment: @SteveB I added the shell location to my answer.

Comment: thx :) I'm sometimes wondering why MS has not done this by default (maybe the lack of PowerShell skills for most admins) ?

Answer (score 2):

To keep the solution in the PS house, just do this at the powershell prompt:

```
New-ItemProperty -path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\run -Name Powershell -Value C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -Type string
```